# Javascript object function with options

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to create a function with options. I believe I have to use objects but have failed so far. By options I mean something like that:

```
insertButton({
    settings:{
        value1:'Some text'      
    }
});

function insertButton(settings){
    settings = new Object();    
    document.write(settings.value1);
}
```

Obviously, that won't work but I am trying to show what I mean. Maybe someone could help.

I am asking because right now I have simple function where I can pass values with strict order. With options I want to be undependable of variables order in function. For example:

```
function insertButton2(value1,value2,value3){
    document.write(value1);
    document.write(value2);
    document.write(value3);   
}

insertButton2('a','','c');  //empty commas to skip value2
```

Leaving empty commas to make sure 'c' is value3 is not convenient for me. That is why I would like to try objects, options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just pass into the function an object with the required keys/values:

```
function parameterify(params) {
    console.log(params.isAwesome);
}

parameterify({
    isAwesome : true
});
//logs true
```

You had two mistaknes:

1. There are no names parameters in js, so `{settings:{}}` would pass an object with a key of settings (so that inside of the functions, you'd have to do `settings.settings`)
2. You redeclared `settings` at the top of the function (`settings = new Object();`), which no matter what you pass in will always overwrite it. As a side note, `new Object` is iffy - object literal `{}` is way cooler

Comment: @Alex Yep, that simple! Isn't javascript awesome?

Comment: It is! I am glad I was on correct path. Thank you for shooting out solution so quick. Thank you all guys, I see all replies more or less of the same work around.

@Zirak, a quick question if you dont mind. Is there any common way to conver object to string?

Comment: @Alex There's always `obj.toString()`, but I'll guess that's not what you want to do. For plain ol' objects, you can simply loop over every key and add call `toString` on it. Of course, it'll have to be recursive, since you'll have to do it for every object you find.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Well you're overwriting `settings` to a blank Object in the first line of your function, take that out and it will work...

Edit: Sorry early remove the settings object from the arguments should just be

```
insertButton({
       value1:'Some text'      
});
```

Comment: if i remove the line how you say then it still returns undefined.

Comment: You changed your question... hold on.

Comment: My second example is just to help to explain what I want to achive. Sorry if that is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function insertButton(settings){
    document.write(settings.value1);
}

insertButton({
    value1:'Some text'      
});
```